# Java get the path of a file in my project /bin/ folder?

Tags: java, bin

```
Path FROM = Paths.get // need to get my file in my bin folder called s.txt, how would this be done?
Path TO = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\to.txt");
try {
    Files.copy(FROM, TO);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hi, I would really appreciate help, I basically need to get the path of a file located in my `/bin/path`

Comment: How come you can get the to path ok but not the from?

Comment: Does `Path FROM = Paths.get("C:\\bin\\s.txt");` not work?

Comment: Why would it? I'm trying to get the file from my project, not sure what It's called in Java but in most other languages it's called a reference.

Comment: I need to get the file that's in the bin folder, you know there's bin, src. Hope that cleared up things.

Answer (score 1):

The local path to your project can be found using

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

if your jar thats running is `c:\workdir\myproject\bin\myproject.jar` then `System.getProperty("user.dir");` will return `c:\workdir\myproject\bin`

Heres how you could use it in your code...

```
Path FROM = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/s.txt");
Path TO = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\to.txt");
try {
    Files.copy(FROM, TO);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to get the file that's in the user.dir/bin aka user.dir/bin/s.txt if that makes sense

Comment: Nevermind I found it out:
   String hi = System.getProperty("user.dir");
   String sex = "/bin/s";
      Path FROM = Paths.get(hi, sex);
      Path TO = Paths.get(hi, "/s.txt");
      System.out.println(TO);
   try {
    Files.copy(FROM, TO);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, if using eclipse, go to:

> project; properties; java build path; source; add folder - select bin folder

Then in your code do

```
Path TO = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/bin/s.txt"));
```

Or you can defined the full system path from C:/ like your to path.